# Gson multiple Serialized name same type

Tags: json, parsing

I have a class:

```
public void results{

@SerializedName("object1")
@Expose
private Object1 object1;

@SerializedName("object2")
@Expose
private Object2 object2;

@SerializedName("object3")
@Expose
private Object3 object3;

@SerializedName("object4")
@Expose
private Object4 object4;

@SerializedName("object5")
@Expose
private Object5 object5;

}
```

In essence, all the objects are the same (have same fields and everything else), and the only reason that they are different is because of the json structure. (don't have control over the json structure).

Does anybody know anyway the Gson can be configured to parse an output:

If Serialized name equals "object1", "object2", "object3", "object4", "object5", create an object of Object1 and add them to a list of Object1?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this code:

```
public void results{

@SerializedName("object1")
@Expose
private Object1 object1;

@SerializedName("object2")
@Expose
private Object1 object2;

@SerializedName("object3")
@Expose
private Object1 object3;

@SerializedName("object4")
@Expose
private Object1 object4;

@SerializedName("object5")
@Expose
private Object1 object5;

}
```